# React Button Click Event Update State Value But Not Reflected on Button Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Still learning some ropes of React.

I have the following code where I render a list of buttons:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [buttonList, setButtonList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => { getButtonList()}, [])

  const getButtonList = () => {
    let data = [
      {id: 1, name: 'One', selected: false },
      {id: 2, name: 'Two', selected: false },
      {id: 3, name: 'Three', selected: false }
    ]

    setButtonList(data)
  }

  const ButtonItem = ({ item }) => {
    const btnClick = (event) => {
      const id = event.target.value

      buttonList.forEach((el) => {
        el.isSelected = (el.id == id) ? true : false
      })

      setButtonList(buttonList)
      console.log('buttonList', buttonList)
    }

    return (
      <button type="button" 
       className={ "btn mx-2 " + (item.isSelected ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-outline-primary') }
       onClick={btnClick} value={item.id}>
       {item.name + ' ' + item.isSelected}
      </button>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="card mb-3 rounded-lg">
        <div className="card-body">
          {
            buttonList.map(item => (
              <ButtonItem key={item.id} item={item} />
             ))
           }
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

So the button renders:

```
[ One false ] [ Two false ] [ Three false ]
```

And when I click on any Button, I can see on Chrome React Tools that the value for `isSelected` of that button becomes `true`. I can also confirm that the specific array item for the button clicked in the dev tools for State (under hooks), the value is `true`.

The text for the button clicked does not show `[ One true ]` say if I clicked on button One. What am I missing here?

P.S. Note that I also want to change the class of the button, but I think that part will be resolved if I get the button `isSelected` value to be known across the component.

Code Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-keller-o5mds?file=/src/App.js:666-735

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue:** You are mutating the state object instead of returning a new state reference. You *were* also previously using `===` to compare a string `id` to a numerical `id` which was returning false for all comparisons.

**Solution:** Use a functional update and array.map to update state by returning a new array.

```
const ButtonItem = ({ item }) => {
  const btnClick = event => {
    const id = event.target.value;

    setButtonList(buttons =>
      buttons.map(button => ({
        ...button,
        isSelected: button.id == id
      }))
    );
  };

  ...
};
```

[image: Edit elastic-ardinghelli-3dw61]

**Suggestion:** Factor out the `btnClick` handler, it only needs to be defined once. Curry the `id` property of `item` so you can use `===`.

```
const btnClick = id => event => {
  setButtonList(buttons =>
    buttons.map(button => ({
      ...button,
      isSelected: button.id === id
    }))
  );
};
```

Update the attaching of click handler to pass the item id

```
const ButtonItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={
        "btn mx-2 " +
        (item.isSelected ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-primary")
      }
      onClick={btnClick(item.id)} // <-- pass item.id to handler
      value={item.id}
    >
      {item.name + " " + item.isSelected}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: I can see that the sample CodeSandbox you provided works, but I'd like to understand why the part where I am setting the value directly to the array item didn't work? Also, my id comparison was using `==` because I was aware that the code I have had different type, but I am changing the code to utilize string GUID for IDs.

Comment: @Chett It mostly doesn't work because you saved the same array reference back into state. React uses shallow reference equality checks to determine when the component should rerender.

Comment: I also tried initially to factor out the btnClick function (as you have set in your example) but I was getting some weird error that did not allow for me to pass a parameter. Hence, I have to change it to what I have in my code sample. I have one add'l question though. This line `const btnClick = id => event =>` looks weird to me. Generally I write function like `const fn = (param) => {}`. Where do I learn this stuff?

Comment: @Chett It is a concept called [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). `const fn = (a, b) => {}` where you attach as `onClick={b => fn(a, b)}` is equivalent to `const fn => a => b => {}` where you attach as `onClick={b => fn(a)(b)}` or more directly as `onClick={fn(a)}`. It allows you to store `a` in an enclosure of an instance of the callback. `f(a) = b => {}`

Answer (score 0):

In your `btnClick` handler you are mutating your state, you should create a new value and assign it instead:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ButtonItem = ({ item, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={
        "btn mx-2 " + (item.isSelected ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-primary")
      }
      onClick={() => onClick(item.id)}
      value={item.id}
    >
      {item.name + " " + item.isSelected}
    </button>
  );
};

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [buttonList, setButtonList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getButtonList();
  }, []);

  const getButtonList = () => {
    let data = [
      { id: 1, name: "One", isSelected: false },
      { id: 2, name: "Two", isSelected: false },
      { id: 3, name: "Three", isSelected: false }
    ];

    setButtonList(data);
  };

  const btnClick = id => {
    const updatedList = buttonList.map(el => ({
      ...el,
      isSelected: el.id === id
    }));

    setButtonList(updatedList);
    console.log("buttonList", updatedList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="card mb-3 rounded-lg">
        <div className="card-body">
          {buttonList.map(item => (
            <ButtonItem key={item.id} item={item} onClick={btnClick} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution and it also works. Although I have to mark the answer which got first (Drew Reese) and helped solve the issue + explain some terms. I do appreciate your time as well.